# Why Android TextView wrap text with dots at word start incorrectly (like file extension)?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I try to display text with file extensions in TextView it wraps incorrectly. Text everytime wraps on the last word before the first file extension with the dot at the start.

Code sample:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_regular">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attachFileConditions"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some file extensions: .docx, .jpg, .pdf, .png, .xls, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsx" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is like this:
[image: Result]

Expected result
[image: Expeced result]

Comment: Either you can solve this by using "wrap_content" or "match_parent" for width. or remove (.) full stop sign from the string as android considering that as a sentence. for your test just remove any dot from middle of string. Let's say change ".png" with "png". Next string will automatically wrap string to next line.

Comment: @Ajay-Rlogical "wrap_content" and "match_parent" doesn't help. The result is correct if text without dots before the extension, but it seems more like "dirty-hack".

Answer (score 0):

> Why Android TextView wrap text with dots at word start incorrectly (like file extension)?

Because your `TextView` has static width `300dp`

You need to change / incraese the width of your `TextView`

**Use this**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

**or**

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

**Instead of**

```
android:layout_width="300dp"
```

Comment: Why this should help? I used 300dp just to show an example. The result is the same with match_parent and wrap_content

Comment: @OlegNestyuk i have tested using `match_parent and wrap_content` and it its working fin for me

Comment: It looks good only on "wide" screens and only if the last words without dots. I modified my code in question (text value was changed) and now it not work with match_parent or wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

try changing `app:breakStrategy="simple"` or which ever suits you best. [breakStrategy reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the breakStrategy options helped.